# what's the purpose of the '--delete-after' option of wget?

Tags: wget

I came across the "--delete-after" option when I was reading the manpage of wget ?
what's the purpose of providing such an option ? Is it just for testing the page is ok for downloading ? Or maybe there are other situations where this option is useful, I hope you guys may give me some hints.

Comment: From the wget manpage - "It is useful for pre-fetching popular pages through a proxy, e.g.:  `wget -r -nd --delete-after http://whatever.com/~popular/page/`". It can also be used to trigger regular maintenance scripts to be run on some systems, where things like cron don't exist. Scripts that don't really produce any output, but are called to do a quanta of work.

Comment: See also `--spider` which could sometimes be used to achieve the same result.

Comment: @arunkumar, I understand its usefulness in buffering for others behind the same proxy. Can you explain how to trigger regular maintenance scripts more specifically ?

Comment: @yorua007, if I write a maintenance script for a client, I need some way to call it. One way is to add a cron job on the webserver, but some servers don't allow that. Another way is to write a webpage that calls that script (e.g. http://example.com/rotate-backups.php), and to visit that webpage from my PC. My PC _does_ allow cron, so I use wget --delete-after to automate that script and clear away after.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With reference to your comments above. I'm providing some examples of how we use it. We have a few websites running on Rackspace Cloud Sites which is a managed cloud hosting solution. We don't have access to regular cron.

We had an issue with runaway usage on a site using WordPress because WP kept calling wp-cron.php. To give you a sense of runaway usage, it used up in one day the allotted CPU cycles for a month. Anyway what I did was disable wp-cron.php being called within the WordPress system and manually call it through wget. I'm not interested in the output from the process so if I don't use --delete-after with wget (`wget ... > /dev/null 2>&1` works well too) the folder where wget runs would get filled with hundreds of useless logs and output of each time the script was called.

We also have SugarCRM installed and that system requires its cron script to be called to handle system maintenance. We use wget silently for that as well. Basically a lot of these kinds of web-based systems have cron scripts. If you can't call your scripts directly say using php on the machine then the other option is calling it silently with wget.

The command to call these cron scripts is quite basic - `wget --delete-after http://example.com/cron.php?parameters=if+needed`

Comment: When would you say --delete-after is appropriate compared to --spider?

Comment: @Paolo when you need to trigger a particular action on the server by either doing a POST or GET but then you don't need the output then `--delete-after` is fine. `--spider` simply checks for the existence file and can't be used for something like doing a POST request.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using wget (with cron) to automate commands to a web application, so I have no interest in the contents of the pages.  --delete-after is ideal for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for testing if a page is downloading ok, but usually it's used to force proxy servers to cache their contents.

If your sitting on a connection where there's a network appliance caching content between the site and your endpoint, and you have a site that's popular among users on that network, then what you may want to do as a sysadmin, is to use a down level machine just after the proxy to script a recursive "-r" or mirror "-m" wget operation.

The proxy appliance will see this and pre-cache the site and it's assets, thus making site accesses for uses after said proxy a bit faster.

You'd then want to specify "--delete-after" to free up the disk space used unless your wanting to keep a local copy of all sites you force to cache.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you only need to visit a website to set an IP address - say if you are rolling your own dyn dns service.